# jquery iterating over elements and binding an event onto each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I need to bind a keypress event to a form of elements that is built up dynamically, see below

```
<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="firstname1" id="firstname1">
<input type="textbox" name="lastname1" id="lastname1">
</div>

<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
</select>
<input type="textbox" name="firstname2" id="firstname2">
<input type="textbox" name="lastname2" id="lastname2">
</div>

... and repeat..
```

I need to check that whenever any of the elements above are changed that no other of the elements are empty.

The form also has several other elements in it although I only care about these highlighted in the code segment.

Many thanks,

I've tried the following code

```
$('.Customer').each(function (index) {

    alert("test");  // alerts the correct number of customer rows

    $("input:textbox").click(function() {
        alert("");
    })

});
```

solution should work with jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: it's not very clear what your goal is

Comment: please see above, have added more to help you.

Comment: the input:textbox is an attempt to bind an event to each textbox although this fails.  this is also flawed i believe as this wouldnt attach an event to the dropdown and it would also attach events to the fields within the form that I am not interested in.

Comment: i don't know where you're getting a :textbox selector from, or where you get type="textbox". the correct selector is ":text" and type is "text". i have a feeling the DOM doesn't understand keypress for a weird input type as "textbox"

Comment: well..  i just need to iterate over the 3 elements that are repeated x number of times and attach an event to them.  is that possible?

Comment: @JamesRadford you should attach ONE event handler to a common ancestor, not a different handler for every single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M4vqZ/8/)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" disabled="disabled">

<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
    <option value="1.1">1.1</option>
    <option value="1.2">1.2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="firstname1" id="firstname1">
<input type="text" name="lastname1" id="lastname1">
</div>

<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
    <option value="2.1">2.1</option>
    <option value="2.2">2.2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="firstname2" id="firstname2">
<input type="text" name="lastname2" id="lastname2">
</div>​

$('.Customer input, .Customer select').bind("change keyup", function(){
     var me = $(this);
     var clicked = me.attr("name");
     var empty = false;
     $('.Customer input,select').each(function(){
         var elem = $(this);
             if (elem.val() == "") {
                 empty = true;
             }
     });
     if (empty) {
        $('#test').attr('disabled','disabled')
     } else {
        $('#test').removeAttr('disabled')
     }
});​
```

PS: there's no type textbos in input. It's text. In order to get a callback fired when something changed you use the "change" and not the "click" event. If you want it to work on both the inputs ans the dropdowns, you need "input, select"

Comment: from the looks of the code this will only work for the checkboxes but not the dropdowns?

Comment: thanks for this although we're using jquery version 1.3.2 and it doesnt seem to work?

Comment: you should've written that in the question. Se my updates, now it works on 1.3.2

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12298/discussion-between-james-radford-and-gavriel)

Comment: @James? After I solved you the problem plus 3 other things not mentioned here you disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach event handlers on each of those text input you should do

HTML ( type is "text" not "textbox" )

```
<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
</select>
<input type="text" name="firstname1" id="firstname1">
<input type="text" name="lastname1" id="lastname1">
</div>

<div class="Customer">
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
</select>
<input type="text" name="firstname2" id="firstname2">
<input type="text" name="lastname2" id="lastname2">
</div>
```

js

```
$('.Customer').each(function (index) {
        $("input:text", this).click(function() {
        alert("");
    })

});​
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/pSFj3/

EDIT - i wanted to point out that you were using a wrong syntax, but as many point out there are bettere ways for handling events. for example you could use event delegation

```
$('.Customer').on( 'click', 'input:text', function() {
   alert('clicked on input');
});
```

Comment: I think he thinks he must use each function, but actually it isn't needed.

Comment: @ocanal i wanted to point out that he was using a lot of wrong syntax, but you are right, he's better of using event delegation to handle events so that he uses fewer handlers

Comment: This code doesn't check "that no other of the elements are empty". Mine answer does.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach a click-event to every textbox within an element of class "Customer", shouldn't this work:

```
$(".Customer input[type=text]").click(function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the form is being built dynamically on the client you will need to use the [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.Customer input[type="text"]', function() { ... });
```